# Using Regex and regexp_replace to Extract values in between known characters in Spark df using python

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark-sql, regexp-replace

I have a column in my data called `col1`, and I'm trying to extract only the value *after the colon and before the close brackets* so I end up with `target`.

```
| col1 | target |
| --- | --- |
| {"0":1} | 1 |
| {"0":5} | 5 |
| {"0":112.0} | 112.0 |
```

I currently have a double use of `withColumn()` and `regexp_replace()` to first remove `{"0":` and then to remove the final `}`, but I want to simplify it.

`df.withColumn('target', regexp_replace('col1', r'\{"0":' ,'')).withColumn('target', regexp_replace('target', r'\}' ,''))`

Although this technically works, I don't think it's the best way to do it. Is there a better way to combine these into a single regex expression?